# Php Redirects to wrong URL when error hanling (Login)

Tags: php, html, mysql

I need some help to solve this problem.
I currently have a website with a database attached with myphpadmin/sql.

I have a register site that redirects users to this url when the registration fields are empty. (http://localhost/register.php?signup=empty)

the problem i am have is that when i try to login on my login page, i want the user to be redirected to this these two url's when an error or empty fields occures. (index.php?login=empty) and (index.php?login=error). But instead i get redirected to (http://localhost/register.php?signup=empty).

Therefore i think that my buttons on the login page are linked to something that aint right?? But i really cant seeem to solve the problem. So any help would be appreciated.

This is my code.

```
INDEX.php

    <?php session_start(); ?>

<!DOCTYPE html <html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css" />
    <title>CSS Login form</title>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="login">
        <form action="login.php" method="POST">
            <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Username" id="name">
            <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" id="password">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Sign In">
            <input type="button" value="Sign Up" onclick="location.href='register.php';" />
    </div>

</body>

</html> 


LOGIN.php

    <?php session_start();
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) 

{

    include 'dbh.inc.php';
    include 'register.php';

    $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $POST['name']);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $POST['password']);

    //check inputs

    if (empty($name) || empty($password)) {
        header("Location: ../index.php?login=empty");
        exit();
    } else {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_name='$name'";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);
        if ($resulstCheck < 1) {
            header("Location: ../index.php?login=error");
            exit();
        } else {
            if ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                //de-hashing password
                $hashedPasswordCheck = password_verify($password, $row['user_password']);
                if ($hashedPasswordCheck == false) {
                    header("Location: ../index.php?login=error");
                    exit();
                } elseif ($hashedPasswordCheck == true) {
                    //If true log the user in
                    $_SESSION['u_id'] = $row['user_id'];
                    $_SESSION['u_name'] = $row['user_name'];
                    $_SESSION['u_phone'] = $row['user_phone'];
                    $_SESSION['u_email'] = $row['user_email'];
                    $_SESSION['u_zip'] = $row['user_zip'];
                    header("Location: ../index.php?login=success");
                    exit();
                }
            }
        }
    }
} else {
    header("Location: ../index.php?login=error");
    exit();
}


REGISTER.php

    <?php if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    include_once 'dbh.inc.php';

    $dbServername = "localhost";
    $dbUsername = "root";
    $dbPassword = "";
    $dbName = "loginsystem";

    $conn = mysqli_connect($dbServername, $dbUsername, $dbPassword, $dbName);

    $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['name']);
    $phone = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['phone']);
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['email']);
    $zip = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['zip']);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['password']);


    if (empty($name) || empty($phone) || empty($email) || empty($zip) || empty($password)) {
        header("Location: ../register.php?signup=empty");
        exit();
    } else {
        if (
            !preg_match("/[\w\s]+/", $name) || !preg_match("/^(\\+)[0-9]{8,30}$/", $phone) ||
            !preg_match("/[^@]+@[^@]+\.[^@]+/", $email) || !preg_match("/^[0-9]{4}$/", $zip) ||
            !preg_match("/^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9]).{8,}$/", $password)
        ) {

            header("Location: ../register.php?signup=invalid");
            exit();
        } else {
            //Check email
            if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
                header("Location: ../signup.php?signup=email");
                exit();
            } else {

                $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id='$user_id'";
                $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
                $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);

                if ($resultCheck > 0) {
                    header("Location: ../signup.php?signup=usertaken");
                    exit();
                } else {
                    //Hashing of the Password
                    $hashedPwd = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
                    //Insert user to database
                    $sql = "INSERT INTO users (user_name, user_phone, user_email, 
                user_zip, user_password) VALUES ('$name', '$phone', '$email',
                '$zip', '$hashedPwd');";

                    mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
                    header("Location: ../signup.php?signup=success");
                    exit();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head></head>

<body>

    <form class=”this.html” method="POST">
        <label for="name" style="color: blue;">name</label>
        <br>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" />
        <br>
        <label for="password">password</label>
        <br>
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" />
        <br>
        <label for="phone">phone number</label>
        <br>
        <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" />
        <br>
        <label for="email">email adress</label>
        <br>
        <input type="text" name="email" id="email" />
        <br>
        <label for="zip">zip code</label>
        <br>
        <input type="text" name="zip" id="zip" />
        <br>
        <button type="submit" name="submit">Sign up</button>
    </form>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: @Jeff

Thanks for the answer Jeff! I just deleted the include, and now i just get redirected to http://localhost/dashboard/ when i try to execute :)

Comment: _sidenote_: do not mysqli_real_escape_string a password (that you verify later), because it might change the password

Answer (score 0):

On the top of `login.php` you

```
include 'register.php';
```

The consequence is, that register.php gets executed, it sees the missing `empty($name) || empty($phone)...` and redirects to `header("Location: ../register.php?signup=empty");`

The simple solution: remove that `include 'register.php';`

Comment: Thanks for the answer Jeff! I just deleted the include, and now i just get redirected to localhost/dashboard when i try to execute :)

Comment: where is 'dashboard' coming from? Is that another redirect in `index.php`? Or in `.htaccess`? ..because it's never mentioned in the shown code.

Comment: Its the .htaccess not an index.php :)